# How to add incremental builds to Dagger 2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, incremental-build

I could not find solution on this site. To add incremental builds to dagger2. You need to do couple of things. Keep in mind that focusing latest version should be best the way to go specially for gradle and dagger2.

**Dagger version atleast 2.18**

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.18"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.18"
```

**into gradle.properties add:**

```
kapt.incremental.apt=true
```

**You need java 1.8**

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}
```

**kotlin version atleast 1.3.30 and latest gradle tools is better**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2"
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
    }
}
```

**for gradle 3.3.2 in our case atleast version 4.10.1:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

**Now the most important part:**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments << ["dagger.gradle.incremental": "true"]
            }
        }
}
```

Enjoy.

Comment: If you want to have a Q&A style question then you should answer your own question rather than answer within your question and accept your own answer

Answer (score 1):

The part in the build.gradle is no longer required, as this is now enabled by default in Dagger (since 2.24). See https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1120